# Computer security / hacking books, texts and other materials from 1990s and early 2000s

Tags: professional-education

I'm looking for good books, articles, texts, zines, guides, videos or any other materials / resources regarding computer / information security, hacking and related subjects **from 1990's and early 2000's**, let's say till year 2009 at maximum. Mainly materials focused on technical aspects (operating systems, networks, programming, crypto etc.), but would also enjoy essays, stories, novels etc.

I have some books from that era, but would expand this collection to make some comparison how things have (or haven't) changed. Also to learn some topics that are not covered now days. Any good titles or links to such "vintage" material are welcome, especially from the old-timers.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you read  http://www.underground-book.net/

Comment: No, didn't know about that, thank you very much! Give me more if you have :)

Comment: Unfortunately, these types of questions are off-topic as they are completely open-ended.

Comment: Maybe, but it has it's significance for people doing research and who take historical approach into consideration. It's also valuable for those who want to analyse and predict how topics change. We can close this topic after receiving some input, but please allow users to make contribution here.

Comment: Try 2600 Magazine. They now offer digital archives back to 2010 but you may have to search libraries to find older paper copies.

Comment: @MarkSaelic No. The problem here is not that the question is not useful, it's that it is not a good fit *here*.

Comment: @schroeder So where should I put it?

Comment: @MarkSaelic there are multiple forums and discussion groups where this type of question could fit. Reddit, maybe? Also, have you done a date-limited Google search?

Comment: I've done Google date-limited search, Reddit should be fine, but I'm interested in valuable stuff. For example, old timers will probably agree that book "Practical UNIX and Internet Security" was a very good book at that time (and in many cases it is still relevant even today). While security is a very broad area, we can always end-up in "off-topic" discussion, but it is still relevant knowledge, so I believe that restricting such questions here results in general loss for all of us. As we can see, my question has some up-votes, so it brings value - which is what Stack Exch. is all about.